# No me deja dibujar en canvas en version mobile html js

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un canvas en el cual debo poner una firma, este en computadora funciona correctamente pero en versión móvil no funciona, ya intente cambiando la funcion a touchmove pero sigue sin funcionar, he intentado de otras formas pero sin llegar a un resultado positivo, sé que si entra en mobile ya que puse un console.log el cual logro leer en la consola, pero al intentar dibujar en canvas no funciona, no sé qué más me haga falta, la verdad es la primera vez que trabajo con canvas, les dejo el código el cual esta hecho en javascript, html y css.

```js
var limpiar = document.getElementById("limpiar");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width = 200,
    cx = cw / 2;
var ch = canvas.height = 130,
    cy = ch / 2;

var dibujar = false;
var factorDeAlisamiento = 5;
var Trazados = [];
var puntos = [];
ctx.lineJoin = "round";

limpiar.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    dibujar = false;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    Trazados.length = 0;
    puntos.length = 0;
}, false);


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
    dibujar = true;
    puntos.length = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();

}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (evt) {
    redibujarTrazados();
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (evt) {
    redibujarTrazados();
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (evt) {
    if (dibujar) {
        var m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
        puntos.push(m);
        ctx.lineTo(m.x, m.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (evt) {
    console.log('touchstart');
    dibujar = true;
    puntos.length = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();

}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (evt) {
    console.log('touchmove');
    if (dibujar) {
        var m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
        puntos.push(m);
        ctx.lineTo(m.x, m.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}, false);





function reducirArray(n, elArray) {
    var nuevoArray = [];
    nuevoArray[0] = elArray[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < elArray.length; i++) {
        if (i % n == 0) {
            nuevoArray[nuevoArray.length] = elArray[i];
        }
    }
    nuevoArray[nuevoArray.length - 1] = elArray[elArray.length - 1];
    Trazados.push(nuevoArray);
}

function calcularPuntoDeControl(ry, a, b) {
    var pc = {}
    pc.x = (ry[a].x + ry[b].x) / 2;
    pc.y = (ry[a].y + ry[b].y) / 2;
    return pc;
}

function alisarTrazado(ry) {
    if (ry.length > 1) {
        var ultimoPunto = ry.length - 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(ry[0].x, ry[0].y);
        for (i = 1; i < ry.length - 2; i++) {
            var pc = calcularPuntoDeControl(ry, i, i + 1);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(ry[i].x, ry[i].y, pc.x, pc.y);
        }
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(ry[ultimoPunto - 1].x, ry[ultimoPunto - 1].y, ry[ultimoPunto].x, ry[ultimoPunto].y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}


function redibujarTrazados() {
    dibujar = false;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    reducirArray(factorDeAlisamiento, puntos);
    for (var i = 0; i < Trazados.length; i++)
        alisarTrazado(Trazados[i]);
}

function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { //objeto
        x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
        y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px #ccc;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">Su navegador no soporta canvas </canvas>
<p id="limpiar">Borrar</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El evento [touchmove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchmove_event) no cuenta con las propiedades `clientX` y `clientY` como lo tiene `mousemove`, esto se debe a que existe el "multitouch" por lo que puede haber más de un `touch` en un evento.

Para obtener la lista de `touch` haces [evento.touches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/touches), y para tu caso puedes utilizar el primer punto de ellos.

Es decir

Reemplazas

```
var m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
```

Por

```
var m = oMousePos(canvas, evt.touches[0]);
```

```js
var limpiar = document.getElementById("limpiar");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width = 200,
    cx = cw / 2;
var ch = canvas.height = 130,
    cy = ch / 2;

var dibujar = false;
var factorDeAlisamiento = 5;
var Trazados = [];
var puntos = [];
ctx.lineJoin = "round";

limpiar.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    dibujar = false;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    Trazados.length = 0;
    puntos.length = 0;
}, false);


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
    dibujar = true;
    puntos.length = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();

}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (evt) {
    redibujarTrazados();
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (evt) {
    redibujarTrazados();
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (evt) {
    if (dibujar) {
        var m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
        puntos.push(m);
        ctx.lineTo(m.x, m.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (evt) {
    console.log('touchstart');
    dibujar = true;
    puntos.length = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();

}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (evt) {
    
    if (dibujar) {
        var m = oMousePos(canvas, evt.touches[0]);
        puntos.push(m);
        ctx.lineTo(m.x, m.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}, false);





function reducirArray(n, elArray) {
    var nuevoArray = [];
    nuevoArray[0] = elArray[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < elArray.length; i++) {
        if (i % n == 0) {
            nuevoArray[nuevoArray.length] = elArray[i];
        }
    }
    nuevoArray[nuevoArray.length - 1] = elArray[elArray.length - 1];
    Trazados.push(nuevoArray);
}

function calcularPuntoDeControl(ry, a, b) {
    var pc = {}
    pc.x = (ry[a].x + ry[b].x) / 2;
    pc.y = (ry[a].y + ry[b].y) / 2;
    return pc;
}

function alisarTrazado(ry) {
    if (ry.length > 1) {
        var ultimoPunto = ry.length - 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(ry[0].x, ry[0].y);
        for (i = 1; i < ry.length - 2; i++) {
            var pc = calcularPuntoDeControl(ry, i, i + 1);
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(ry[i].x, ry[i].y, pc.x, pc.y);
        }
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(ry[ultimoPunto - 1].x, ry[ultimoPunto - 1].y, ry[ultimoPunto].x, ry[ultimoPunto].y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}


function redibujarTrazados() {
    dibujar = false;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    reducirArray(factorDeAlisamiento, puntos);
    for (var i = 0; i < Trazados.length; i++)
        alisarTrazado(Trazados[i]);
}

function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { //objeto
        x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
        y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px #ccc;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">Su navegador no soporta canvas </canvas>
<p id="limpiar">Borrar</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias era justo lo que necesitaba